# ASP.NET web app (.NET framework) webpack generated files during publish are not copied to target location

Tags: asp.net, webpack, visual-studio-2017, csproj

My *.csproj configuration is following:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" Command="npm run buildDev" />
  <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm run buildProd" />
</Target>
```

When hitting the "Publish" button (Release config - to file system) the command is executed, but the files which are newly created by webpack are not copied to the publish target location:

```
<Content Include="dist\**" Exclude="dist\**\*.js.map" />
```

Is there a way to run npm script before publish picks up the files for release?

I've seen this fixed for .net core 2.0+, but how about ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best solution, but I've found that the following configuration will do the job:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CompileDependsOn>
    $(CompileDependsOn);
    WebpackBuild;
  </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="WebpackBuild" DependsOnTargets="CompileTypeScript">
  <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm run buildProd" />
</Target>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" Command="npm run buildDev" />
</Target>
```